# How to join two entities and map the output to a model?

Tags: java, android, greendao

I'm trying to join two entities using greenDAO and map the output to a model which has both entities' properties. I joined the entities, but I couldn't access the second entity in my model.

Take greenDAO's example for instance, we're trying to join User and Address entities and store the input in a array of type User. I did the exact thing. User and Address entities join successfully, but I can't access Address properties in my User model. I also tried to create an array of addresses in my User model, but I got the "Unsupported type" greenDAO exception.

```
QueryBuilder<User> queryBuilder = userDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.join(Address.class, AddressDao.Properties.userId)
  .where(AddressDao.Properties.Street.eq("Sesame Street"));
List<User> users = queryBuilder.list();
```

What I need is being able to access Address properties stored in my list of type User.

Comment: User SQLite with GSON instead of greenDAO.

Comment: In their docs they say “Let’s consider an entity User, which has a one-to-many relation to an Address entity”. Is it true for your entities?

Comment: @algrid yes my entities have the same relation as the ones in the docs.